# TimePicker spinner mode change color of colon

Tags: java, android, colors, spinner, timepicker

I use `TimePicker` class with `Spinner Mode`. I was wondering if it would be possible to change the color of the [colon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifAyy.png) between the `NumberPickers`.

I'm not looking for two independent `NumberPicker`s and a `TextView` between them.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [layout](https://dl.zjuqsc.com/android/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-Q/data/res/layout/time_picker_legacy_material.xml) used for the spinner-style Material TimePicker, you'll see that the divider is a simple TextView:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/divider" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginStart="6dip" 
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dip" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:importantForAccessibility="no" />
```

A simple way to change it would be to create a style for your picker:

```
<style name="MyPickerTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents...">
    ...
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/myColor</item>
    ...
</style>
```

After that, set the theme for your TimePicker:

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/my_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:theme="@style/MyPickerTheme"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
```